# How to create a Angular pipe that filters a string by substring and removes it

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-services, angular-pipe

I would like to create an angular pipe that filters a string by substring and if the substring occurs, it returns a new filtered string.

The difficulty for me here is that the filter has to work on two separate items.

**Here is the relevant part of my template:**

```
<span class="type">{{ item.type | filterTypeNames }}</span>
<span class="name">{{ item.name | filterTypeNames }}</span>
```

**Here is my pipe:**

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterTypeNames'
})
export class FilterTypeNamesPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string, ...args: any[]): any {
    // Many different substrings are possible here (used 'TEST' for testing)
    if (value.indexOf('TEST') !== -1) { 

    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

**Here is an example of how the pipe should work:**

If the type is "TEST" and the name is "TEST-A1" the pipe should return "TEST-A1". So the substring "TEST" should not be display again.

**So:**

TEST
TEST-A1

**Should became:**

TEST-A1

*..and only be displayed in the span with the class "type". The span with the class "name" should be empty.*

**If name and type are different, then nothing should change. For example:**

TEST
BLABLA-A1

*..should stay the same.*

I currently have no idea how I can combine or compare the values ​​and would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I think you might be better off adjusting the data in your component rather than in a pipe, but you can also provide a pipe with additional parameters like this: `item.type | filterTypeNames:item.name`

Comment: You actually want to create a custom structural directive and not a simple pipe, I am trying to make a demo for you on stackblitz

Comment: @MikeS. Interesting.. Now I get the values I want for filtering inside my pipe. I'm trying to use indexOf now to check if the type occurs in the name as a substring. But how can I return the result then... Very confusing...

Comment: My techlead told me to create a reusable pipe for that, but a directive as an alternative would be nice. Thank you very much.

Comment: Pipes are very simple beings, whatever is returned from the `transform` method is what appears in your template instead of the expression. E.g. `item.type | filterTypeNames` turns into whatever is being returned from the `transform` method

Comment: @MikeS. I've solved it with your approach. Post it as an answer and I'll approve it :)